# Textarea value remain the same after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My previous problem has been fixed, now I need to ask how to keep a textarea from resetting its input after a form is submitted. Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rz4pnumy/

Should I change the form in the HTML?

```
<form id="form1" method="GET">
```

(the form does not go into a php file or anything else, i'm using it to submit the textarea input and use the variables I made using jQuery to make a paragraph on the same page)
or something in the JS?

```
$(document).ready( function () {

  $('#form1').on('submit', function (event) {

    // If the form validation returns false, block the form from submitting by 
    // preventing the event's default behaviour from executing.
    if (!validate()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if(validate()) {
      var adjective1 = $('#adjective1').val();
      var adjective2 = $('#adjective2').val();
      var pluralnoun = $('#plural-noun').val();
      var verb1 = $('#verb1').val();
      var edibleobject = $('#edible-object').val();
      var monster1 = $('#monster1').val();
      var adjective3 = $('#adjective3').val();
      var monster2 = $('#monster2').val();
      var verb2 = $('#verb2').val();

      $('body').append(
        '<div id="para">' +
          '<p>Rain was still lashing the windows, which were now ' + adjective1 +', but inside all looked bright and cheerful. ' +
          'The firelight glowed over the countless ' + adjective2 + '' + pluralnoun + ' where people sat ' + verb1 + ', talking, ' +
          'doing homework or, in the case of Fred and George Weasley, trying to find out what would happen if you fed a ' + edibleobject +' to a ' + monster1 + '.' + 
          'Fred had "rescued" the ' + adjective3 + ', fire-dwelling ' + monster2 + ' from a Care of Magical Creatures class and it was now ' + verb2 + ' gently ' +
          'on a table surrounded by a knot of curious people. </p>' +
        '</div>'
        );
    }
});

function validate() {

  var success = true;

  $('.input').each(function(i, item) {
      if ($(item).val() === "") 
      {
         console.log("Missing textarea input");
         success = false;
         $(item).attr("style","border:1px solid red;");
         //note it will overwrite your element style in all Input class
      }
      else
      {
         $(item).removeAttr('style')
         // to remove border 
     }
   });

    return success;
}
});
```

The contents get emptied after pressing submit and I only see the completed paragraph for a split second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default event handler from executing whether validate passes or not, so you need to remove the if statement around the event.preventDefault() call.  The preventDefault is the function that is keeping the from from submitting and re-loading your page.

Also, your Fiddle was not set to jQuery (it was set to no-library) so that may have also been causing you issues during your testing.

Edited for example of what I'm talking about:

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function (event) {

    // block the form from submitting by 
    // preventing the event's default behaviour from executing.
    event.preventDefault();

    if(validate()) {
        var adjective1 = $('#adjective1').val();
        var adjective2 = $('#adjective2').val();
        var pluralnoun = $('#plural-noun').val();
        ... etc ...
```

Comment: And I was testing on my local drive, I uploaded to jsFiddle because fellow stack overflow coders prefer the link to visualize it.

Comment: If I remove the preventDefault call, then won't it submit even when validate is false?

Comment: preventDefault() does what it sounds like it does - it prevents the default action of the event handler (which is a submit).  Since you are taking care of the request on the client side, you never want the form to actually submit to the server.

Comment: In case my answer wasn't clear, you NEED the preventDefault() call, you just don't need the if statement surrounding it.  Currently, your code only does a preventDefault when the form isn't valid, so if the form IS valid then it will not preventDefault, and it will then submit to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would use php and set a variable to the GET value of the textarea and set the value of the textarea to that variable